# SQL Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = 300

Tags: sql-server

I'm really new in Microsoft SQL Server, I'm trying to update the value of a  column to null. But it gives 'Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = 300.' In the table design, this column's datatype is tinyint(allow nulls is clicked). Please help!

> Update tblMedicationOrder   set MedicationID = Null

Comment: Do you want to set all rows in column table as NULL? because you didn't add a where clause

Comment: If a column is of datatype `tinyint`the range for values is from 0 to 255! But i don't think the error you get comes from your update statement! Except there is a FOR|AFTER|INSTEAD OF   UPDATE trigger on your table...

Comment: @CeOnSql: Thank you very much! There's a Trackupdate trigger on this table.

Comment: a real classic :) you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

**There is not an error in the your code..**
**You should make sure that set null value.**

[Tinyint range = 0 to 255](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

If you enter a value greater than 255, it gives this error.

*Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = 300.*